# How to properly use qRegisterMetaType with multidimensional arrays?

Tags: qt, multidimensional-array

I want to use something like

```
typedef double Matrix[4][4];
```

to represent transformations and also pass them around with the QT signal/slot mechanism. But when I use

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Matrix)
```

it throws an error in qmetatype.h at this function

```
void *qMetaTypeConstructHelper(const T *t)
{
    if (!t)
        return new T();
    return new T(*static_cast<const T*>(t));
}
```

saying: "error C2075: 'Target of operator new()' : array initialization needs curly braces"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(T)` requires the type `T` to be default-constructable, copiable and destructable. Your `Matrix` type is not copiable, thus you can't use `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` on it.

Workaround: use a class.

```
// copiable, C++98 brace-initializable, etc.
struct Matrix {
    double data[4][4];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should be using [eigen3](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) and its types. Alternatively, wrap your type in a class. Once you do it, you might as well have the class do more than be a mere wrapper. Eventually, you'll see that eigen3 is the only sane way to proceed. Probably when you get to this point:

```
#include <cstring>

class Matrix {
    double m_data[4][4];
public:
    typedef double (*Data)[4];
    Matrix() {}
    Matrix(const Matrix & other) { memcpy(m_data, other.m_data, sizeof m_data); }
    Matrix & operator=(const Matrix & other)  { memcpy(m_data, other.m_data, sizeof m_data); return *this; }
    Matrix & operator=(const Data other)  { memcpy(m_data, other, sizeof m_data); return *this; }
    operator Data() { return m_data; }
};

int main()
{
    double mat1[4][4];
    Matrix mat2;
    mat2[3][3] = 1;
    mat2 = mat1;
    return 0;
}
```